# Pycharm: How to adjust color of variable/syntax highlighting?

Tags: python, pycharm, syntax-highlighting

I'm not entirely sure if it's called syntax highlighting, but when I have my cursor over certain words in the editor, it will highlight other occurrences of it. The problem is, with the theme I'm using (warm neon), the highlighting is quite blinding on my screen. To be clear, I'm not talking about selecting text with the cursor, I mean when I have my cursor in the middle of certain words, it will change the background and font color of that word, and do so with other occurrences.

How do I adjust the color? I can't seem to figure it out in Preferences.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

These are defined in the the [Colors and Fonts](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/colors-and-fonts.html) dialog.

Go to `File` -> `Settings` -> `Editor` -> `Colors and Fonts`

You will want to look under `General`. The specific ones you are looking for are `Identifier under caret` and `Identifier under caret (write)`

[image: PyCharm colors]

Answer (score 0):

Configuring Colors and Fonts

With PyCharm, you can maintain your preferable colors and fonts layout for syntax and error highlighting in the editor, search results, Debugger and consoles via font and color schemes.

PyCharm comes with a number of pre-defined color schemes. You can select one of them, or create your own one, and configure its settings to your taste. Note that pre-defined schemes are not editable. You have to create a copy of a scheme, and then change it as required.

You can view how the new scheme looks in the editor. To do that, just click Apply without closing the Settings dialog box.
To configure color and font scheme

1. Go to file -> Open Settings, and under the Editor node, click Colors & Fonts.
2. Select the desired scheme from the Scheme name drop-down list.(Darcula for black screen)
   If you need to change certain settings of the selected scheme, create its copy. To do that, **click Save as button**, and type the new scheme name in the dialog box.